# Google Apps Script - 'Relational Database' or 'Inheritance'?

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have 2 spreadsheets that handles student data.

First spreadsheet - Student's personal information (Name, Identification, Email..etc.)

Second spreadsheet - Student's leadership progress, After-school activities..etc.

So here comes the problem..there are over 1000 students. If one student leaves, I have to open both spreadsheet and delete the student's name on both spreadsheet.

I was wondering if there's a way for OOP/Inheritance or get apps script spreadsheet to behave like a relational database.

Comment: Create an input mask to delete a student ID and run a script to delete every row with that id from both sheets?

Comment: oop/inheritance are unrelated concepts for what you ask. only relevant part is making a script to do it, run from a custom menu item.